# routing incoming traffic to dummy interface

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

have default interface eth0 with ip address 192.168.0.100, I created a dummy interface with ip address 192.168.5.100

I have traffic coming through eth0 that I would like to have forwarded to 192.168.5.100.

I am not sure how to make the packets go to the dummy interface, how do I set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need todo much on the machine where the dummy interface is installed. It mainly boils down to `enabling ip forwarding`.

How this is done depends entirely on which operating system is installed on the machine with the dummy interface.

However you need to make an entry in the router, so it knows where to find to find the subnet `192.168.5.0/24`.

In your router there should be a place where you can make a `static route`.

Here you need to tell the router that the subnet `192.168.5.0` with the submask `255.255.255.0` is located at `192.168.0.100`.

Again how this is done depends entirely on what kind of router you have installed.

Comment: there's no router, I am trying to do everything from 1 machine, its routing traffic from one interface eth0 to a dummy interface veth0

Comment: You need a router if any other device on your LAN needs to communicate with `192.168.5.100`. The alternative is you add a static route entry to each other device on your LAN telling them how to reach the same ip. How the routing is handled **internally** on the machine with the dummy device depends on the operating system involved. You should edit your question with more details in that case.

Comment: I do not need any other devices to connect to 192.168.5.100. just this one host with a connection to that particular ip address.